# Saving username in a key, and load the key if exist

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am going to create an anonymous login system in my application.

What I want is:

> 1. The person opens my application
> 2. The person clicks the "Enter" button, and it will check if a user key exists.
> 3. If the user key exist, it will log in with the username inside the user key
> 4. If the user key does not exist, it will log in using the anonymous code below, and save the username in a key, so it can use the same username
>      later, without needed to create a new anonymous username.

Anonymous user login code:

```
PFAnonymousUtils.logInWithBlock {
    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil || user == nil {
        println("Anonymous login failed.")
    } else {
        println("Anonymous user logged in.")
    }
}
```

How can i do this? How can i create the key, set the key, load the key etc..?

Comment: Why aren't you just using the anonymous user provided?

Comment: @Wain - Because if there are thousands of user logins each day, that will be a lot of users created. And this system will make it easier for me to control over.

Comment: All you need to do is check that `PFUser.currentUser` isn't nil - if it isn't then the user is already logged in (anonymously). If it is nil then call your code above.  Once an anonymous user is logged out in Parse, you can't log back in as that user.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Hm, can i make it that when the user is logged out, it deletes the user?

Comment: That is how PFAnonymous users work as far as I know - https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFAnonymousUtils.html#//api/name/logInInBackground - at least as far as the users table is concerned. If you have created other objects in Parse they won't be deleted.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Ah that sucks.. So if i have 1 million users logging in daily, it will be created over 1 million users each day? And in 1 year i will have over 365 million users in my parse database?

Comment: It is hard for me to comment because I don't know whatnot are doing with your app. Typically the anonymous user is used to allow some functionality before a persistent user is created and an anonymous user can be converted so they don't lose content/history. Even if you don't convert users then the anonymous user will persist until the user "logs out". If you don't provide a logout function then this will only be when your app is deleted/reinstalled. You will only get the numbers you listed if you have 1 million new users every day. This is why you check that current user is nil before login

Comment: @Paulw11 - Oh, my app is like Instagram, but without users. They can upload images/video, but not using account; anonymous.

Comment: Ok, so don't provide a logout button. Also, this is only my opinion but your app probably won't be approved by Apple because of clause 18.2

Comment: @Paulw11 - What about this: http://pastebin.com/0TwHzMtd

Comment: Not really because if the user is anonymous you can't log in as that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to save the user id because an anonymous user only exists as long as it is logged in anyway.  If the anonymous user is logged out then you can never log in as *that* user again.  From  the [Parse Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFAnonymousUtils.html) -

> Once logged out, an anonymous user cannot be recovered.

But, unless you provide a logout button in your app then the user will only be logged out when the app is deleted/re-installed.

So, you can just use something like this

```
if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
    PFAnonymousUtils.logInWithBlock {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil || user == nil {
                println("Anonymous login failed.")
            } else {
                println("Anonymous user logged in.")
            }
        }
}
```

If the user is already logged in then you don't have to do anything, otherwise log in anonymously

Comment: But the user is still there, in the database. It will not be deleted, and that will make ALOT of users in my parse database.

Comment: Only if you have a lot of users.  You could store a "last activity" date in the PFUser table and purge users that haven't logged in for a 6 months or a year or whatever

Comment: It will be like this: http://s27.postimg.org/rtcidehkz/Screen_Shot_2015_10_05_at_00_17_58.png

Comment: How can i do that? The last activity thing?

Comment: Add a date column to the user object, set it to the current date when the user starts the app?

Comment: And what about the delete part? To delete the user if no activity for 1 week?

Comment: Use a cloud code background job in Parse to identify the users and delete them.  I think a week is a bit aggressive though - if someone runs the app after 8 days then they will have a problem.  Its not like the rows in the table cost you anything much.

Comment: But i thought you said that a person can only access a anonymous account 1 time? So when someone opens the app, he gets username"HFowdiajodj", and then close app. And when he opens again, he get a new username"NfckaLAKfw". Correct?

Comment: Ah now i understand. A anonymous user will be there all the time, unless the user delete or log out from it. If the user only quit the application, the anonymous user will still be there, therefor, i use this: http://pastebin.com/Cy8jUCNK

Comment: yes, exactly.  Parse already persists the user login session for your app between runs

Comment: Awesome, made it work perfect now! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: A last question.. Can you tell me the difference between these: http://s21.postimg.org/i9gwolah3/Screen_Shot_2015_10_05_at_01_01_39.png ?

Comment: An installation represents an installation of your app on a device - typically independent of user, but you may track the currently logged in user for purposes like pushing to a specific user.  Users you know, sessions relate a specific user's login on a device.  If you are using anonymous users it won't apply to you

Comment: Hm, but what if someone keeps posting scam images and i want to "ban" the user from my app. Can i do this easy with the setup i have now with anonymous users?

Comment: Well you can delete the anonymous user from Parse but then your app will just create a new one.  This is why I suspect your app won't be approved

Comment: How would you suggest to do this? This app named YikYak is something like that, but only text, not images.

Comment: You need to have a "flag content" button and have people actively reviewing, responding and removing content.  Even with registered accounts it is hard to prevent banned user  from registering a new account, but it is a little harder than if they use anonymous logins.  You can track identifierForVendor and block the app on devices associated with banned users but even then they can delete/re-install to get a new identifierforvendor

Comment: So there is no way i can get something like deviceID or anything from the person who uploaded the image? And then put the deviceID in a "blockedUsers" list? And in application start i check if device is blocked or not?

Comment: You can get `identifierForVendor` but this resets if the device is reset or the app is deleted/re-installed

Comment: So if i use `identifierForVendor`, how should i set this up?

Comment: You could collect the `identifierForVendor` value and add it to a class in Parse.  When you ban a user set a flag on that row and look up `identifierForVendor` before allowing the app to operate in the future.  If it is banned then display a suitable message to the user

Comment: Ok so i managed to add the `identifierForVendor`  on the image uploaded like this: http://s15.postimg.org/542ba6lfv/Screen_Shot_2015_10_05_at_01_58_29.png, - but how to set the ban check?

Comment: You need to run a `PFQuery` against that value when the app starts

Comment: How can i do a query like if self.identifierForVendor exist in class "banned"?

Comment: I MADE IT WORK YES! Thank you OMG!!!